# r-leaflet addAwesomeMarkers() not showing up when using markerCLusters

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a leaflet map that shows AwesomeMarkers appropriately, but when I add `clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions` to the arguments, none of the markers are displayed.

I'm following the examples here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html (see Awesome Markers section).  The examples do work for me, so it doesn't appear to be caused by anything on my system.

```
dat <- structure(list(lat = c(34.6525609, 34.8323176, 34.623637, 40.436154, 
                       40.7253178, 41.5696682, 41.5965959, 41.6237623, 41.6277843, 41.6610833
), lng = c(-87.1206101, -87.1905764, -87.0325887, -85.3813609, 
           -86.2186063, -70.6142768, -70.5854606, -70.5527536, -70.5209656, 
           -70.4868442), restrict_category = c("Limit", "Limit", "Ban", 
                                               "Limit", "Limit", "Ban", "Ban", "Ban", "Ban", "Ban")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
sf_states <- states(cb = T) %>%
  rename(state = NAME) %>%
  shift_geometry(geoid_column = "GEOID") %>%
  st_transform("EPSG:4326") %>%
  filter(STATEFP < 60)

leaflet(dat) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = sf_states, weight = 2, color = "#000000", opacity = 1, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = "white") %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers()
```

[image]

Same code as above but with clusterOptions set:

```
leaflet(dat) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = sf_states, weight = 2, color = "#000000", opacity = 1, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = "white") %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  )
```

[image]

Trying to make the coords into an sf yields the same blank map as above:

```
dat_sf <- st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("lng", "lat"), crs = 4326)

leaflet(dat_sf) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = sf_states, weight = 2, color = "#000000", opacity = 1, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = "white") %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  )
```

```
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
 os       macOS Monterey 12.4
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/Denver
 date     2022-07-12
 rstudio  2022.02.3+492 Prairie Trillium (desktop)
 pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 broom         0.8.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cachem        1.0.6   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 class         7.3-20  2022-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 classInt      0.4-7   2022-06-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 clipr         0.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 crosstalk     1.2.0   2021-11-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 DBI           1.1.3   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 dbplyr        2.1.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 devtools    * 2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 dplyr       * 1.0.9   2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 e1071         1.7-11  2022-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 forcats     * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 foreign       0.8-82  2022-01-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 haven         2.5.0   2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 hms           1.1.1   2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 htmlwidgets   1.5.4   2021-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 httr          1.4.3   2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 KernSmooth    2.23-20 2021-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lattice       0.20-45 2021-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 leaflet     * 2.1.1   2022-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 lubridate     1.8.0   2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 maptools      1.1-4   2022-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgbuild      1.3.1   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 pkgload       1.3.0   2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 processx      3.6.1   2022-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 proxy         0.4-27  2022-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 ps            1.7.1   2022-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rappdirs      0.3.3   2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.8.3 2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 readr       * 2.1.2   2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 readxl        1.4.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rgdal         1.5-30  2022-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rlang         1.0.3   2022-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 rvest         1.0.2   2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sf          * 1.0-7   2022-03-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 sp            1.4-7   2022-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 styler        1.7.0   2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tibble      * 3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tidyr       * 1.2.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tigris      * 1.6     2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 tzdb          0.3.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 units         0.8-0   2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 usethis     * 2.1.6   2022-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 uuid          1.1-0   2022-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 xfun          0.31    2022-05-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)

 [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add addTiles() to the code

```
leaflet(dat) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = sf_states, weight = 2, color = "#000000", opacity = 1, fillOpacity = 1,
              fillColor = "white") %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  )
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why?  I do not want tiles.

Comment: I am not able to explain JS interactions and dependencies.